# css class not cascading, on anchor tag

Tags: css

I am targeting the class .menu-item-16, as I want to change the anchor text color     specific only to this class. But, the browser matches the CSS values of default theme's over my custom code.

My CSS file has theme default code

```
.news-entry li a:visited {
    color: #A84949;
}
```

my code

```
.menu-item-16 a, .menu-item-16 a:active, .menu-item-16 a:link, .menu-item-16 a:visited    {
    color: green;
}
```

but at the browser, when I usee toolkit, it matches, theme default code, and my code is followed below.

please help me. I been searching for hours without luck.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was nonsense... Could you provide a html example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the "li":

```
.news-entry li.menu-item-16 a, .news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:active, .news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:link, .news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:visited     
{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving id to anchor tag, something like:

```
#menu-item-16 a {
    color: green;
}
```

or you can also try giving "!important" to the class css.

```
.menu-item-16 a{
    color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the specificity to match the default theme CSS. Try the following (note the `li` before the `a`):

```
.menu-item-16 li a, 
.menu-item-16 li a:active, 
.menu-item-16 li a:link, 
.menu-item-16 li a:visited    {
    color: green;
}
```

Also note that in order for it to properly cascade your style rules need to come after the default theme CSS.

===>>> EDIT <<<===

assuming .menu-item-16 *is* the li from the default CSS, you will need to use the following.

```
.news-entry li.menu-item-16 a, 
.news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:active, 
.news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:link, 
.news-entry li.menu-item-16 a:visited    {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but I think the html looks like `<li class="menu-item-16"><a ...>`

Comment: Just revised my solution, is it a correct assumption that .menu-item-16 is the same as the li from the default theme?